# Why are the electrons coming back with 1V?

Tags: transistors, current, electronic-load

[image]

The current is in conventional flow , it enters the battery.

Is it possible that the electrons that go out of the current source come back to it with 1000mV?

Comment: In this case, current source terminal voltage of 1000 mV is required to maintain current flow in this circuit of 18,724,527,222,000,000 electrons each second....that's about 3 mA.
If terminal potential difference were less than one volt, too few electrons would be available to maintain a current of 3 mA. Terminal voltage rises or falls to keep current flowing at that constant rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to answer your questions straight away, but I feel it's important to analyse this circuit formally, so we have a clear understanding of the relationship between the battery voltage and the voltage across the 2kΩ resistor (and the current source). After I've done that, I'll try to address your confusion.

I'll start with the usual application of Kirchhoff's current and voltage laws, and Ohm's law, to derive the relationship between the battery voltage and the voltage across the 2kΩ resistor, so we can plot a graph. I'll redraw the schematic with everything labelled to make it easier:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6rFyL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'll be referring to the voltages across the various components as \$V_{NAME}\$, so that \$V_{BAT1}\$ is the difference in voltage between its positive and negative terminals, and \$V_{R1} = V_{BAT1}- V_X\$.

I am going to declare that the negative terminal of the battery is at 0V (that's the meaning of the ground symbol, bottom left), so I can state absolute potentials with reference to that "zero-volt" node:

$$ V_X = 0V + V_{R2} = V_{R2} $$

My goal, then, is to determine \$V_X\$ as a function of \$V_{BAT1}\$. Let's start by applying Kirchoff's Voltage Law (KVL) to make some statements about the voltages in this circuit. For the loop consisting of BAT1, R1 and R2, we can take a walk around it, taking note of the potential changes as we jump across each component. When we arrive back where we started, we must get back to the same voltage we started at, in the same way that if you take a walk around town, over bridges, and up and down hills, when you get gack to where you started, you must end up at the same elevation you began with. Starting at the battery negative (0V) and walking counter-clockwise around the loop, algebraically we get:

$$ 0V + V_{R2} + V_{R1} - V_{BAT1} = 0V $$
$$ V_{R1} + V_{R2} = V_{BAT1} $$

Now I'll apply Ohm's law, to replace \$V_{R1}\$ and \$V_{R2}\$, and get an expression in terms of the currents, and the known resistances:

$$ I_1 \cdot R_1 + I_2 \cdot R_2 = V_{BAT1} $$

Kirchhoff's Current Law (KCL) allows us to make statements about the relationships between the various currents in the system. At node X, KCL tells us that the sum of all currents into that node must equal the sum of all currents leaving it, in the way that a junction in a water plumbing system cannot have more (or less) water leaving it than entering:

$$ I_1 = I_2 + 3mA $$

Plugging this expression for \$I_1\$ into the previous expression, we can get a equation for \$I_2\$, in terms of \$V_{BAT1}\$:

$$ (I_2 + 3mA) \cdot R_1 + I_2 \cdot R_2 = V_{BAT1} $$

$$ I_2 \cdot R_1 + 3mA \cdot R_1 + I_2 \cdot R_2 = V_{BAT1} $$

$$ I_2 \cdot (R_1 + R_2) + 3mA \cdot R_1 = V_{BAT1} $$

$$ I_2 = \frac{V_{BAT1} - 3mA \cdot R_1}{R_1 + R_2} $$

Lastly, noting that \$V_X\$ is the voltage across \$R_2\$ (\$V_{R2}\$), I apply apply Ohm's law again, to obtain \$V_X\$, as a function of \$V_{BAT1}\$:

$$ V_X = V_{R2} = I_2 \cdot R_2 = \frac{R_2 \cdot (V_{BAT1} - 3mA \cdot R_1)}{R_1 + R_2} $$

Here's a graph of that relationship:

[image]

Note that that when \$V_{BAT1} = 15V\$, \$V_X = +1V\$, in agreement with your simulation.

The first thing about your thinking that needs correcting is your reference to "electrons". It is true that electrons are indeed the moving charges repsonsible for electric current here, but we rarely, if ever, need to think about them.

For one thing they are negatively charged, and move from regions of low voltage to regions of higher voltage which is counter-intuitive. Fluid flows from high pressure to low, information moves from people who know a lot about something to those with less knowledge, objects "fall" from a place where they have high gravitional potential energy to where their potential energy is lower.

As engineers, we wish to maintain this idea of flow from high potential to low, to simplify the arithmetic. Otherwise we have negative signs everywhere, and the maths gets hellish quickly. So we make use of symmetry, in that positive charges moving in one direction through some conductor have exactly the same effect on that conductor as an equal amount of negative charge going the other way. So we don't deal with electrons, we deal with fictional positive charges. And we almost never care about individual charges, we concern ourselves almost exclusively with the en-masse flow of these fictional positive ones, which we call "conventional current".

Now, if you insist on talking about individual charges, then that's fine, but you really must understand what voltage means in that context. The voltage (potential) at some point in a circuit is a measure of the potential energy possesed by all charges at that point, relative to the energy they would possess at some other point. It's always relative to some other point, because we can't know the actual *absolute* electical potential energy of a charge if we don't know where in the entire cosmos is the point of zero potential energy (or even if there exists such a point), that we can use as a universal "zero" reference. Maybe it's at the center of the Earth, or the Sun, or at the Milky Way's central black hole. Who knows?

It's a universal law of physics that things tend towards a state of lower potential energy, and therefore we can state that if there exists a higher potential at some point in the circuit than at some other point, and there exists a path that charges can move through to traverse that "potential difference", then they will accelerate towards that point of lower potential.

Importantly, this is no guarantee that they will ever get there. If you reverse the potential difference somehow, before they arrive at their destination, their direction of motion will also reverse, and they have a new destination, at which they also may never arrive. All you can say is that in the presence of some potential difference, there will be a flow of an unimaginable quantity of positive charges in the direction towards the lower of the two potentials. Or, if you insist on talking about electrons, those charges will move to the higher of the two voltages, but that's just confusing, so don't do that.

So, armed with an understanding of how charges behave when they find themselves between two points of differing voltage, I can begin to answer your original question: "Is it possible that the electrons that go out of the current source come back to it with 1000mV?". I want to start with R2, and I'll get to the current source later.

When the voltage at the top of resistor R2 (\$V_X\$) is 1V higher than the voltage at the bottom, then each positive charge at point X will have exactly 1eV (one electron-volt) more potential energy than any charge found at the bottom of R2. Conversely, every *electron* at the *bottom* of R2 has exactly 1eV more potential energy than electrons found at the top, but again, let's leave electrons out of this. All those charges will flow, *if permitted* (and R2 does permit them to flow), from where they have higher potential energy, in the direction of lower potential energy.

This brings us to a glaring contradiction to that principle, which can be seen in the graph above. When \$V_{BAT1} < 12V\$ then \$V_X\$, the voltage across the current source, is negative. I can assure you that (conventional) current is now flowing upwards through R2, but the current source seems to be violating the rules by maintaining a downwards current flow, from low potential to high, in direct contradiction to everything I've just said.

That's because current sources don't exist in real life, at least not the "ideal" ones you find in simulators. In real life you cannot have such a situation in a ciruit without any reactive components (like capacitors and inductors), and without dynamically varying voltages.

A simulator is able to implement "negative resistance", which is a component whose current becomes more positive (rises) as the voltage across it becomes more negative (falls). That's not something you find in nature (with a few exceptions that don't apply here), and this "ideal current source" is behaving just like a negative resistance. It may only be considered an analytical tool, able to produce conditions that cannot occur in the real world.

In real life, no circuit consisting of only voltage sources and resistances could ever produce a voltage outside of the range provided by those sources. In your circuit, BAT1 defines the minimum and maximum voltages that could possibly be present anywhere, from 0V to \$V_{BAT1}\$. In this simulation, though, you see \$V_X\$ becoming negative for certain values of \$V_{BAT1}\$, indicating that the current source must effectively be a negative resistance when \$V_{BAT1} < 12V\$. Charge motion in that condition is analogous to a ball rolling uphill in spite of gravity pulling it the other way. That's like the ball having a negative mass, which is ridiculous (or is it?).

So, paraphrasing your question, "Is it possible that the charges can emerge from a component with more potential energy than they entered?", the answer is:

- In a simulator, yes, anything can happen.
- In real life, no, this cannot happen. It's possible to give that impression using a hidden voltage source inside a "black box current source", but that's not in the spirit of the question. That would be cheating, because such a voltage source can impart potential energy to charges without you even knowing, what with it being hidden.

Answer (score 0):

If the battery voltage is  -10 volts then there will be 1 volt across the current source.

That 1 volt will push 0.5 mA into the 2 kΩ resistor and there will be 2.5 mA (the remainder) flowing into the 4 kΩ resistor. To get 2.5 mA flowing through a 4 kΩ resistor, requires the voltage across it to be 10 volts hence, the battery terminal connected to the 4 kΩ resistor must be at -10 volts with respect to the indicated 0 volt line on your diagram.

That means the battery voltage is -10 volts.

Comment: i 'tried' with different voltages on the battery this is 15v but when it is low like 5v the current source's current go through the 2k , but in this 15v example it's the battery's electrons that go through the 2k, but maybe i still don't know why the voltage is negative

Comment: Stop talking about electrons. For simple circuits like this we talk about conventional current flow measured in amps or milliamps etc. My answer is telling you that if there is 1 volt across the 2 k resistor then the left node of the 4 k resistor has to be at -10 volts with respect to 0 volts. My answer doesn't have room for optionally trying other things out i.e. if you don't use a 10 volt battery of the correct polarity then you won't get 1 volt across the 2 k resistor.